# PHP - Special letters in form?

Tags: php, forms, character-encoding

I have a working contact form, but am experiencing the following problem: The site is mainly serving Finnish content and the form doesn't really like scandinavian letters (ä, ö, å) The email looks all garbled up and goes directly to spam mail. I've tried changing the HTML charset, but it didn't do anything.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Artotek - Yhteydenotto</title>
    </head>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

        // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
        $email_to = "artjom@europe.com";
        $email_subject = "**Yhteydenotto**"; 

        function died($error) {

            // your error code can go here
            echo "Olemme pahoillamme, mutta lomakkeestasi löytyi virhe(itä). ";
            echo "Alapuolella näet virheesi.<br /><br />";
            echo $error."<br /><br />";
            echo "Ole hyvä, ja mene takaisin korjaamaan nämä virheet, ja yritä uudelleen.<br /><br />";
            die();

        }

        // validation expected data exists
        if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
            !isset($_POST['email']) ||
            !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
            !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
            died('Lomakkeessasi oli ongelmia');       
        }

        $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
        $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
        $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
        $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
        $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

        $error_message = "";
        $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
        if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
            $error_message .= 'Sähköpostiosoite ei ole käytössä.<br />';
        }

        $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'Etunimesi ei näytä olevan oikea.<br />';
        }

        if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
            $error_message .= 'Sukunimesi ei näytä olevan oikea.<br />';
        }

        if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
            $error_message .= 'Viesti ei täytä vähimmäisvaatimuksia.<br />';
        }

        if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
            died($error_message);
        }
        $email_message = "Lomaketiedot alla.\n\n";

        function clean_string($string) {
          $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
          return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
        }

        $email_message .= "Etunimi: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Sukunimi: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Sähköposti: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Puhelinnumero: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
        $email_message .= "Viesti: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

        //create email headers
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers, 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n");

        /*
        $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
        'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
        //@mail($email_to2, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
        */
    ?>
    <!-- include your own success html here -->
    <div style="text-align: center; background: lightgreen; top: 50%; position: absolute; left: 0%; box-shadow: gray 5px 3px  5px;">
    <font face="century gothic"><h1>Kiitos yhteydenotostasi. Otamme teihin yhteyttä; piakkoin.</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 60%; right: 15%; text-align:center; background: red; width: 30%;">
    <a href="index.php" style="color:inherit; text-decoration: none;"><h2>Takaisin</h2></font>

    <?php

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in your `clean_string` function. It looks like you're poorly trying to prevent header injection, but you're not applying it to the header at all.

Comment: Well I found the sample in the internet. I know very less PHP myself.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to craft a mail yourself using mail, I suggest you pick up a library like 'swiftmailer' - http://swiftmailer.org/

This will deal with the character set issues, as well as setting boundaries on multi-part mails and suchlike in a way that reduces your chances of hitting spam filters.

"mail" sounds like an easy solution, but as soon as you want to anything other than a plain text mail in ASCII it'll be far more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Sounds like me :) Just... faster!

Comment: True, and there are many other options.  But trust me (and @mathieu-dumoulin), setting up a library like this will be far less complicated than trying to roll your own mail functions.

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, you might want to check the real file encoding of your file, stating the charset at the top doesn't mean your file is encoded this way.

2) Use a tried and testing mailing library like swift mailer, zend mail or PHPMailer to send your emails, apart from sending simple text based ASCII emails, i don't know many hardcore developpers that try to send mail with "mail()", they all use libraries!

3) Use a email testing/preview application to make sure your email gets out correctly in all clients. I've once lost 6h trying to figure out why my mail was looking bad, and with a tool i don't remember the name now, i saw that it was only in my client it was bad, others were fine... It gave me the tip i needed to finish it cause i knew i was searching for a specific problem not an at large one!